# Windows directory locker implementation

Tags: windows, directory, dir

** I want to do this for educational cause only, for myself, not to replace any system that is already implemented in the Windows OS **

I want to implement some kind of directory locker in Windows 10.
In order to do so, I want my program to run in the background, and every time it will identify a try to access a directory, it will search whether the directory is locked or not, and if it is locked, it will pump up a password insertion box.

I want to start by pumping up the password message box (first stage), and after that to actually block the access if the password is wrong (second stage).

Any leads?

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing stopping the user from just killing your program and accessing the directory as normal. If you want to prevent someone from accessing something, use access controls -- that's what they're for. If the user is an administrator they can change the access controls to undo what you do; but if the user is admin they could just debug any program or process and completely replace the code that does the access check with code that does nothing.

Comment: I want to do it for a personal use, publication is not on the line.

Comment: 1. This is a terrible answer and not useful at all.

Comment: @Asheh The question asks for something fundamentally not supported by the platform, that the platform actively works to prevent from existing. It's the best answer you're going to get.